# Can Expo be used with Firebase cloud messaging at all?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo, create-react-native-app

Can I use CRNA or Expo with Firebase Cloud Messaging?  If so, how? The Firebase JS lib ?   Looks like I can but how to make push notification work?

or ExpoKit with Firebase Android/IOS lib?

Thanks!

Comment: First result for "expo and firebase": https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase.html - please search before asking.

Comment: I have refined my question, thanks.

Comment: No, Expo doesn't support notifications. You'll have to eject.

Answer (score 3):

> If you need to use the full Firebase SDK, with Firebase Analytics,
>   Firebase (rather than Expo) Push Notifications, Firebase Crash
>   Reporting, and Firebase Links, you will need to eject for the
>   foreseeable future

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/full-native-firebase-integration

Comment: This list doesn't include Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 2):

here is updated document from expo showing they support FCM with Android: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v26.0.0/guides/using-fcm